# How do I connect a bluetooth device to Windows with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth device, I want to connect it to Windows with Python, almost exactly how you do it with the UI just programmatically. How could I achieve this? I assume I should use the win32 api but I would love some guidance.
It seems [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothauthenticatedevice) is the function that I need to use, but I cant seem to even run it; not sure how.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of device is it? Bluetooth classic or BLE? What do you want to do once you are connected? For classic there is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62815818/7721752 and for BLE there is https://github.com/hbldh/bleak

Comment: Not sure what type it is, it's a Nintendo Switch Joycon, Google says Bluetooth 3.0 but I'm not sure how useful that is. EDIT: I am trying Bleak already but it's not finding it (while windows bluetooth is)

Comment: Bluetooth 3.0 would fall under the classic category. However, the previous solution I linked to is for RFCOMM and not game pads/HID. You might need to go for something like https://pypi.org/project/winrt/

Answer (score 0):

you can try using PyBluez, I found that to be easier to use
https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez

docs: https://pybluez.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

if you are on windows 10 you need to install some dependencies described here

Comment: I did try PyBluez but it couldn't find my device (windows was finding it), PyBluez was finding my phone though, just not the device I wanted it to find.

Comment: have you installed the correct dependencies? I had a similar problem and I solved installing the windows 10 sdk from the docs

Comment: and also make sure your other device is discoverable try visualizing it via your phone's bluethoot menu

Comment: Could it be because the device I am connecting want's to be the child of my computer but the phone wants to be the parent of my computer? Don't know how to really say it.