# Importing bluetooth module to python environment on windows 10

Tags: python, bluetooth, windows-10

I am trying to develop a program to allow communication between my windows PC and a Raspberry Pi via bluetooth. Things have been moving smoothly on the Pi, but on my PC I cannot seem to get the `bluetooth` module to work correctly and I haven't seen anyone with the same error message I am getting.

I have pybluez installed, but when I try to import the bluetooth module I get the following error message: `module 'socket' has no attribute 'BTPROTO_RFCOMM'`. I get this error message when all I run is `import bluetooth`.

I also tried using sockets but I get the error: `module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_BLUETOOTH'`.

I am wondering if I am missing something that is causing my socket module to not work.

Comment: There are probably better Bluetooth libraries on Windows 10. If you are doing Bluetooth Classic then Python's Socket library support that https://stackoverflow.com/a/62815818/7721752. If it is Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) then Bleak might be better https://github.com/hbldh/bleak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making a virtual environment and using `conda install pybluez` just in the environment. This also only worked in certain python versions for me: 2.7 and  > 3.9. I canonly run the code from the command line, but works fine now!

Comment: Consider marking this answer as correct by pressing the checkmark.